# how to read contact in android

Tags: android

i am developing an android sms app in which i want to read contact number from contacts using following code

```
 Intent ContactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            ContactPickerIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(ContactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
```

it is working fine on emulator but not on device. what changes should i make to make it run on the device.

here is my onactivityresult function

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
     {  
         switch (requestCode) 
         {  
         case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
             Cursor cursor=null;
             try
             {   
                 Uri result = data.getData();
                 Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: " + result.toString());

                 // get the contact id from the Uri     
                 String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                 // query for everything contact number  
                 cursor = getContentResolver().query(  
                      Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  
                      Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",  
                      new String[]{id}, null); 

                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                 int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);  
                 if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                 {   
                     phonenofromcontact = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                     finallistofnumberstosendmsg +=","+phonenofromcontact;
                     Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got phone no : " + phonenofromcontact);  
                 }
                 else 
                 {                                
                     Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results"); 
                 }
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to get contact number", e);
             }
             finally
             {
                 if (cursor != null)
                 {  
                     cursor.close();
                 }
             }
             phonePhoneno= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonenofromcontact);
             phonePhoneno.setText(finallistofnumberstosendmsg);
             //phonePhoneno.setText(phonenofromcontact);
             if(phonenofromcontact.length()==0)
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "No contact number found for this contact",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
             }
            break;  
         }  
     } 
     else
     {  
         Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
     }  
 }
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it crashing? Or returning no contacts? More information, please!

Comment: it is not returning contact number. should i provide code of on activityresult function too to make it more clear??

Comment: can you show your onActivityResult function here too.

Comment: Do you want to pick particular contact or read all contacts from contact book?

Comment: @KernowBunney question updated.

Comment: @PareshMayani i want to read all contact as i have mentioned in the question . i m developing an sms app which'll send sms to user accessing  his contact no from the contact list.

Comment: please provide some solution...m waiting for response

Comment: Patience, please! Solution provided, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering your intent using:

```
ContactPickerIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

which tells the Contacts Provider to only return contact information that contains the Phone content type.

Therefore the ID returned by the Contacts Provider is the `_ID` of the `ContactsContract.Data` table - not the `CONTACT_ID`

Try changing your cursor query to this:

```
 // query for everything contact number  
 cursor = getContentResolver().query(  
              Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  
              Phone._ID + "=?",  
              new String[]{id}, null);
```

That should return you the selected contacts number.

As an aside, the data query that you originally wrote would have worked if you had not called `ContactPickerIntent.setType` on the Intent (**if you have made the above change - then you still need to call this!)**

It probably worked on your emulator by luck - I am guessing that maybe you have one contact with one phone number on your emulator? It is likely that both the `CONTACT_ID` and the `_ID` of the Data table are both 1, which would, by coincidence, return the correct row.

Comment: not working same message "no contact number found for this contact"  it means phonenofromcontact.length()==0 as it is written over there in the code.

Comment: Are you sure? That fix worked for me when I pasted your code into an Activity. What did you try: changing the CONTACT_ID to _ID, or removing setType? P.s. DON'T DO BOTH !!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the permission `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` to your AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: i have already taken that permission. as i  have mentioned it is working on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Need the permission in android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" >
    </uses-permission>
```

And this is my working code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @kaidul islam sazal it is working but our requirement is something different ..i want to  read contact number and add to edittext in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
// query for everything contact number  
                 cursor = getContentResolver().query(  
                      Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  
                      Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",  
                      new String[]{id}, null);
```

to

```
// query for everything contact number  
                 cursor = getContentResolver().query(  
                      Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  
                      Phone._ID + "=?",  
                      new String[]{id}, null);
```